# Resolve current directory inside visual studio code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble resolving the current directory inside Visual Studio Code (using $PSScriptRoot) which simply evaluatues to nothing when in the IDE. This breaks several scripts, what is the workaround for this and what should you use to make it work inside Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Works for me. Visual Studio Code v1.7.2 running on Fedora 24. PowerShell v6.0.0-alpha.9. PowerShell plugin for VSC v0.7.2

Comment: I'm running VS Code v1.7.2 with Management Framework 4, it's not working for me... PS Plugin also 0.7.2

Comment: This works for me also.  Running on Windows 8.1.  Please note, if you're running in debug, you can control the cwd within the launch.json file.

Comment: Found the issue. I was always running code using F8 but thats run selection which apparently has no concept of what file its running in. Used Run Code instead and that resolves it fine.